# Pubnub search channel by message text

Tags: ios, search, pubnub

We have a react-native chat app which uses pubnub. We need to search messages/channels by keywords like WhatsApp search functionality. Can we achieve the same in pubnub?

using pubnub library:
pubnub": "^4.28.1"

We have a call to fetch messages (history API). Do we have filter/search support to get messages with particular text?

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no ability to specify filter parameters to the history API based on message text.   Many developers leverage PubNub's ability to encrypt messages which would prevent the platform from inspecting the content of the messages, so search typically needs to happen on the client side on the unencrypted messages.

Comment: Furthermore, PubNub Sales Engineers can assist you with the best practices to accomplish what you need to do whether it is client-side search or search on your own server (self-hosted or otherwise) using your own database. PubNub has simple "message forwarding" features and other design patterns that will facilitate this requirement.